# iPhone-AR toolkit - Does not update points on the radar when device starts moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, iphone-ar-toolkit

I have implemented the iPhone-AR toolkit app found in this link.

https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit

I want to re plot the radar points everytime device starts moving i.e. Everytime the current lat long values change, the existing set of values should change their position on the radar . But it does not move the points present on the radar. Can anyone tell me where I have to change to implement this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try Calonso's ar-kit project which is similar to yours since they are both forked from same repository: https://github.com/calonso/ios-arkit